# function hook_menu_alter on metatag module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have 2 users on my drupal7 website(client and user1(admin)). I'd like that client user, using metatag module has access to only 1 tab(By Path tab) or metatag:context node.
If i use function hook_menu_alter:

```
function MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
$items['node']['access callback'] = FALSE; 
}
```

will this deny that client user to use other tabs of that module?

So function would look like this

```
function Metatag_menu_alter(&$items) {
$items['admin/config/search/metatags/settings']['access callback'] = FALSE; 
}
```

Correct me if im wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook_menu_alter does not know the context of your user, that function there would deny all access to all users for the page admin/config/search/metatags/settings
What you are wanting is to actually define a callback function.  This piece is called "access callback" because menu router calls back to the listed function to determine access at the time that someone is visiting the page.

```
function Metatag_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['admin/config/search/metatags/settings']['access callback'] = 'metatag_admin_access'; 
}

function metatag_admin_access() {
  global $user;
  if( [check your metatag context] ) {
    // this user is permitted
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```